# message.guild.channelCreate is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I feel ridiculous asking for help on this so in advance I apologize, but I got this error in my code when trying to create a channel. Here is my code:

```
 if (message.author.bot) return;
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (msg.startsWith("create channel")) {
        const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ')
        message.guild.createChannel(`${args}`).then(channel => {
            channel.setTopic('Test')
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to use the wrong function in v12. [`Guild#channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) is a [GuildChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager) in v12 instead of a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection).

Replace `message.guild.createChannel` (v11) with `message.guild.channels.create` (v12). Note that you can also set the topic in the same API call by passing options to [`GuildChannelManager#create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) like so...

```js
message.guild.channels.create(args.join(" "), { topic: "Test" })
```

See [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) on updating your code from v11 to v12.

Comment: Hi! thank you for the reply, I tried the code and I got this error: Invalid form body name

Comment: Weird, can you try replacing `args` with ````${args}```` as you have in your question

Comment: okay i tried that, it then switched to "could not interpret ${args} as a string"

Comment: Sorry I meant ${args} surroudned by two `  like you have in your question, stackoverflow converts it to markdown

Comment: ah, okay. Same error as before sadly. Invalid form body name

Comment: Can you console.log args and tell me the output?

Comment: @AliceBardout `args` is an array. When Node's converting `args` to a string, the actual output looks like `[ 'foo', 'bar' ]`. You need to use `args.join(' ')` (or use whatever delimiter they were originally split at) to form the arguments into a string properly.